# How can pass two parameters to rawQuery in android?

Tags: android

I can use the following code to pass one parameters to rawQuery

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable where numberType=?", new String[] { "2" });
```

Now the following code is right?

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable where numberType=? and id=?", new String[] { "2","5" });
```

Comment: Yes. Have you tried it?

Comment: It's correct. Any problem with that?